# Writing a IBM-Cognos expression to filter dates between custom ranges

Tags: datetime, filter, expression, cognos, calculated-field

I'm trying to write an expression in Cognos Analytics to return my data points within a certain range. My data is organized similarly such as in this picture with dates and names all the way back to June (06-01-2023) (picture attached):[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJqnZ.png)

Is there an expression where I can return the names between the current date and two weeks prior? Ex, current date being 09/21/2023 and two weeks prior to that.

I've tried [Request Create Date] BETWEEN current_date AND _add_days(currentddate, -14)

but no luck unfortunately as the error is "The result of a calculation cannot be boolean expression"

Thank you

Comment: NEVER MIND I FIGURED IT OUT. I had to reverse the _current_date and the _add_days(current_date, -14). 

[Request Create Date] BETWEEN _add_days (current_date, -14) AND current_date  

had worked. Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Please include sample data (sample input, expected output, current output) as text, not as a picture.  And if you are going to answer your own question, please answer it - not in a comment.  Otherwise, delete the question as it will have little or no lasting value to the site.